# Mocking specific method in tests not working

Tags: python, python-unittest

I'm using Python 3.5.2. I'm trying to mock up the same methods under different test cases, but it seems that `sys.argv` doesn't get mocked up.

I've also tried to use `@patch` decorator instead, but no avail.

`main.py`:

```py
from os import path
from sys import argv

globals = {}

def get_target_dir():
    if len(argv) < 2 or not path.exists(argv[1]):
        print("You must specify valid full path of instances directory as command line argument.")
        exit(1)
    globals['TARGET_DIR'] = argv[1] + ('/' if argv[1][-1] != '/' else '')
```

`tests.py`:

```py
import unittest
from unittest.mock import patch
from main import get_target_dir, globals

class TestMain(unittest.TestCase):
    def test_correct_target_dir(self):
        argv = [None, '/test']
        with patch('sys.argv', argv), patch('os.path.exists', lambda _: True):
            get_target_dir()
            assert globals['TARGET_DIR'] == argv[1] + '/'

    def test_invalid_target_dir(self):
        argv = [None, '/']
        with patch('sys.argv', argv), patch('os.path.exists', lambda _: False):
            try:
                get_target_dir()
            except SystemExit:
                assert True
            else:
                assert False
```

When I run the tests, because of the problem above they don't work as expected.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've realized I didn't know about [gotchas](http://alexmarandon.com/articles/python_mock_gotchas/#patching-in-the-wrong-place), so I wrongly included `sys.argv` method in `main.py` - after replacing the import `from sys import argv` to just `import sys` (and further putting `sys.` before `argv` in the code) everything started to work.